# Need parameter "File"?

Tags: java

I need some help with this...

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        setWallpaper( ? ? ? );
    }

    public void setWallpaper(File file) throws Exception
    {
        String as[] = new String[]
        {
            "osascript",
                "-e", "tell application \"Finder\"",
                "-e", "set desktop picture to POSIX file \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"",
                "-e", "end tell"
        };

        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        Process process;
        process = runtime.exec(as);

        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

I want to make a small program that changes the desktop for the Mac OS. I searched online and found the setWallpaper method, but I haven't figured out how to use it. I try to call it at the start but I need a parameter "File". I don't know what to put in there. This should be very easy for someone else... but I am very new to java. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your main method, you'll want to instantiate a File object and pass it in so that the setWallpaper method knows what file it's going to use.

```
File aFile = new File("path/to/file");
setWallpaper(aFile);
```

You could of course combine that into one line like:

```
setWallpaper(new File("path/to/file"));
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose the file is present in `Desktop/MyPics/Pic.jpg`

you can call `setWallpaper()` like following

```
setWallpaper(new File("Desktop/MyPics/Pic.jpg"));
```

Comment: The pathname should be encased in quotations since it's a String. :)

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure, but doesn't this expect an absolute path, or a relative path to the package?  If you want to use a root directory outside of the scope of this package, you'd have to start at absolute root, unless you used getProperty("user.home") to concatenate with the start of the path.

Comment: i just gave an example and did not include any drive name etc. as he is using Mac

Comment: Desktop isn't the root of a mac though, it'd be more like /Users/[theuser]/Desktop/MyPics/Pic.jpg.  Just to avoid any confusion.

Comment: i fully agree but i hope our answers would have solved user's problem